# Run all the python script files as sudo

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I'm trying to run a python script as sudo. Easy :

```
sudo python main.py
```

But this file call another file :

```
import getdata
```

And getdata call a package :

```
import spidev

# Establish SPI device on Bus 0,Device 0
# need sudo rights!
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
```

But when I run my script as sudo, I get :

```
[Thu Aug 27 23:56:16 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.31] Premature end of script headers: main.py, referer: http://192.168.1.50/moisture/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/moisture/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/var/www/moisture/twitter.py", line 7, in <module>
    import getdata
  File "/var/www/moisture/getdata.py", line 14, in <module>
    spi.open(0,0)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How can I run all the file as sudo?

Comment: Are you sure about the line `spi.open(0,0)`. Check if another process is not using already the same device. Anyway if you run `main.py` with sudo, everything that's called from `main.py` is run with sudo (root) privileges (if the user is not set explicitly anywhere else) therefore the `Permission denied` error is caused by something else.

Comment: try putting this line #!/usr/bin/python on the very beginning of your main file, then do: sudo chmod +x main.py on the terminal and run it with ./main.py , let me know the result.

Comment: There's no need for [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) if he is running it explicitly with python. (`sudo python main.py`)

Comment: http://quick2wire.com/non-root-access-to-spi-on-the-pi/

Comment: From the SpiDev documentation (http://tightdev.net/SpiDev_Doc.pdf): "Because the SPI device interface is opened R/W, users of this module usually must have root permissions."

Comment: Thanks jlyoung! You found my problem!! :D